# Simple way to remove tags (not content) matching a CSS selector?

Tags: scripting, server-side, pandoc

Is there a simple approach to process an HTML file so that tags matching a certain CSS selector can be deleted? My motivation is that `pandoc` generates HTML output that in my view is too verbose, surrounding any math expression with `<span class="math inline"> ... </span>`, when generally `...` is enough. For display math the input and output tend to have line breaks, so maybe a dedicated tool would be better than `grep` or similar. The goal is to reduce bandwidth usage, so anything client-side would be out.

Comment: Which language are you using? Is it server-side or client-side? Did you try something so far?

Comment: @NeriBarakat It's an language-agnostic question, in fact mostly interested in seeing if there is some tool well suited for this (maybe `lxml`?). I believe using `tr` to temporarily change EOLs into some unused character, and then `grep` for characters `<span class="math inline">\([^<][^<]*\)</span>` should do it, but I'm asking to know if there's something more elegant.

Comment: pandoc inserts those span tags to enable javascript libraries like mathjax to display the math properly... you can of course remove them with your html processing tool of choice, e.g. nokogiri if you're using ruby...

Comment: @mb21 I just realize you added a comment, thank you. I understand pandoc adds those span tags for styling, but I don't think MathJax uses those classes, does it? I haven't come across it their documentation. Needless to say, unless you use a generator such as pandoc adding all those tags for every expression would be a nightmare. By the way, thanks for the pointer about nokogiri! (I would accept something like that as an answer. I was looking for tools.)

Comment: @ezequiel-garzon ok, made it into an answer. btw, seems mathjax has two modes (one with dollars and one with spans) http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/jsMath.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandoc inserts those span tags to enable javascript libraries like mathjax to display the math properly... you can of course remove them with your html processing tool of choice, e.g. Nokogiri if you're using ruby, Put something like this in `removespans.rb`:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(File.open("file.html"))
doc.search('span').remove
puts doc
```

then execute:

```
pandoc -s -o file.html input.md
ruby removespans.rb > output.html
```